# How to change a cell value in data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

Let say I have below data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
DF = data.frame('A' = 1:4, 'B' = letters[1:4])
```

Now I want to change a specific value -

```
DF[DF[, 'B'] == 'a', 'A'] <- 9999
```

How can I use `dplyr::pipe` function to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: in new version of `dplyr` use `mutate(across(...))` rather than `mutate_at`:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(A, replace, B == 'a', 9999))

     A B
1 9999 a
2    2 b
3    3 c
4    4 d
```

Here's how you can accomplish the above using a `pipe` (`%>%`):

```
DF %>%
  mutate_at("A", ~replace(., B == 'a', 9999))

     A B
1 9999 a
2    2 b
3    3 c
4    4 d
```

Explanation: you are mutating "at" the variable called "A", so whatever function you call on it will mutate it in place (rather than creating a new variable). You can use `~` instead of the typical syntax `function(x)` to call an anonymous function that will automatically take `.` as its argument. Wherever you place `.` in the function it will operate on the column "A". You use the replace function on `.` (column `A`), to replace the value 9999 everywhere that the statement `B == 'a'` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Why `mutate_at()`? That seems a bit over-engineered for this task. We are only changing one variable so a regular `mutate()` does the job, without the added complexity of the anonymous function etc.

Comment: @Till It's an automatic check that the `"new column name" == "old column name"`. Possibly unnecessary, but i prefer it because this way if you enter a typo in `mutate` and name the variable something other than "A", you will unwittingly have an extra column (A and also the-A-typo-column). If you do that in `mutate_at`, you instantly get an error message and your script stops

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::replace()` work well for this task.

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(A = replace(A, B == "a", 9999))
```

`mutate()` creates a variable A, so after execution, it will overwrite the existing variable A, then `replace()` replaces the value in A with `9999` whenever B equals "a".

Finally you want to store the result, so the full code looks like this:

```
DF <- 
 DF %>% 
 mutate(A = replace(A, B == "a", 9999))
```